# How to extend a field with a multiline message

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I have a logstash conf like so:

```
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/path/to/mycert"
    ssl_key => "/path/to/mykey"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "logs" {
    if [message] =~ /^\d\d\d\d/ {
      grok {
        match        => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:other_field} %{GREEDYDATA:content}" }
        add_field    => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
        add_field    => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
      }
    }
    multiline {
      pattern => "^\d\d\d\d"
      what    => "previous"
      negate  => true
    }
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

Here's a sample log:

```
2015-04-09T04:56:37.548Z OtherField Send message:
Keepalive {
  Type: keepalive
  key: ABCDE
  time Thu Apr 09 00:56:37 EDT 2015
}
```

The content field ends up with the string "Send message:\n" and nothing else. We want the content field to extend and contain: "Send message:\nKeepalive {\n  Type: keepalive\n  key: ABCDE\n  time Thu Apr 09 00:56:37 EDT 2015\n}"

I've tried using `add_field`, but I can't even convince it to add a simple field (ie, `"multilinemsg", "true"`) let alone extend the content field.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you give an example of your log file and what are you trying to achieve? -- Asaf.

Comment: Sorry ... I missed your comment for some reason. Just added the requested info.